# Travel Medical Insurance for a Romanian visa

Tags: insurance, romania, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian Ph.D. student and am going to apply for a Romanian Visa in Italy, Rome. I want to stay in Romania for 3 months. I asked the Romanian Embassy for the required documents. The Romanian embassy told me that I should have travel medical insurance that covers the entire duration of the requested period of stay. So, I need help about which kind of insurance I should buy.